# Hibernate Replicação de tabela com sequence

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Boa Tarde, 
Em uma aplicação em que estou trabalhando temos uma tabela chamada tb_perfilparametrovalorpdv, segue o mapeamento

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_perfilparametrovalorpdv")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "gen_perfilparametrovalorpdv", sequenceName = "gen_perfilparametrovalorpdv", allocationSize = 1)
public class PerfilParametroValorPDV implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id_perfilparametrovalorpdv", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "gen_perfilparametrovalorpdv")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "tx_descricao", nullable = false)
private String descricao;

@Column(name = "dt_cadastro", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreationTimestamp
private Date dataCadastro;

@Column(name = "dt_manutencao", nullable = true)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@UpdateTimestamp
private Date dataManutencao;

@Column(name = "nr_sincronizacaoversao", nullable = true)
private Long sincronizacaoVersao;

@Column(name = "dt_exclusao", nullable = true)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dataExclusao;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parametroValorPDV", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ParametroValorPDV> parametroValorPDVs = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parametroValorPDV", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<VinculoPerfilPDV> vinculoPerfilPDV = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Possuimos duas aplicações rodando em bancos de dados separados, onde denominamos uma de Multi e outra de Terminal.
Sendo que no Multi criamos os registros e utilizamos o sequence, e no terminal apenas sincronizamos os registros.
Passamos as informações do Multi para o Terminal através de uma API REST, passando inclusive o id gerado pela sequence no Multi, porém ao tentar efetuar a persistência no terminal pelo código

```
   @Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void sincronizarCarga(List<PerfilParametroValorPDVDTO> listDadosRemoto) throws Exception {

    if (!ListUtil.isNullOrEmpty(listDadosRemoto)) {

        List<PerfilParametroValorPDV> perfis = modelMapper.map(listDadosRemoto,
                TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, PerfilParametroValorPDV.class).getType());

        perfis.forEach(perfilParametroValorPDVRepository::save);
    }
}
```

O Hibernate ignora o id passado pelo DTO e tenta gerar um novo. Existe alguma forma de fazer o hibernate ignorar a sequence quando receber um id?

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal consegui resolver criando um custom generator.

Segue códigos:

```
package br.com.sysmo.server.pdv.repository.generators;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator;

public class S1ServerPDVCustomGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

@Override
public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {

    Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(object.getClass().getName(), object).getIdentifier(object, session);

    if (id != null) {
        return id;
    }

    return super.generate(session, object);
}
```

}

e no modelo:

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen_perfilparametrovalorpdv", strategy = "br.com.sysmo.server.pdv.repository.generators.S1ServerPDVCustomGenerator", parameters = {
    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "gen_perfilparametrovalorpdv"), @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
    @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1") })
```